# Image to Text Conversion - Rails 4/5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I cant seem to see anything in my searches.

I am trying to find a Rails 4 or 5 gem/plugin that acts similar to when you hold the camera to an app store card and it converts the text on the card to an object.

in my case i want a user to submit a photo and it reads two boxes in the screen shot / photo and converts the text in the image to text to save to an appropriate field and saves on from submit..

is there anything like this out there or am i just thinking a bit too far out of the box here..??

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you're ready to invest a lot of time and probably money.
What you're looking for is OCR (Optical character recognition). ABBYY makes finereader which is a business solution for OCR. It's probably the best you can hope for at this point. There probably are quite a few open source solutions out there that will work more or less well.
Check out this project (or find similar ones): https://sourceforge.net/projects/tesseract-ocr/

Comment: OCR!!! Thanks that's what was evading my mind! thanks for the quick response! I am doing this dev for a non-prophet so expensive isn't the best but youve put me on the right track! cheers!